# Angular Currency pipe with decimals

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-pipe, currency-pipe

I have my input with currencyPipe, it works, but sometimes i need to add decimals numbers, but with the code that i'm using i can't do it.

```
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(res => {
  if(res.total_actives_amount){
    this.form.patchValue({
      total_actives_amount: this.currencyPipe.transform(res.total_actives_amount.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/^0+/, ''), 'USD', 'symbol', '1.0-0')
    }, {emitEvent: false});
  }
})
```

I think that the problem is this line:

```
total_actives_amount: this.currencyPipe.transform(res.total_actives_amount.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/^0+/, ''), 'USD', 'symbol', '1.0-0')
```

Answer (score 1):

The transform method inside currency pipe has the following parameters:

```
transform(
   value: string | number,
   currencyCode: string,
   display: string | boolean,
   digitsInfo: string,
   locale: string
) {...}
```

The **digitsInfo** takes the following format:

`{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}`

the value you specified for the digitsInfo is `1.0-0`

minIntegerDigits = 1

minFractionDigits = 0

maxFractionDigits = 0

to display decimal numbers you have to change `minFractionDigits` and the `maxFractionDigits` to a larger number than 0

**for example**

`1.1-3`

this will show at least one decimal number and at most 3 decimal numbers

reference [angular.io/currency](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe#parameters)